Why was never contracted to ne'er?
This question is inspired by the same poem of Byron's as this one. The third line of the excerpt seems to have originally been written as:

To guard those relics ne'er to be restored.

This is something I've always wondered - I can maybe see why this contraction was used in poetry for a marginally shorter meter, but why does it exist in the first place? Why was it common enough for the word to have 1 letter dropped that it become such a popular contraction, and at what point was that no longer the case that it became entirely subsumed by never?

It's still pronounced that way in the word ne'er-do-well.

Ever became e'er. Possibly other variants too. But you won't get an answer to your questions. There's not a Poetic Abbreviations Department deciding what's allowed.

@StuartF Are you implying that these contractions came from and were exclusively used in poetry, or maybe just literature, and never general use?

Loss of a sound is called elision. While elision of the sound /v/ didn’t occur systematically in English, it has occurred in various high-frequency words such as “had” and “has” (compare “have”, though this also has a weak form without /v/ as in “shoulda”) and in a common pronunciation of the word “of”.
The answers to this Quora post list more examples: Why was "v" dropped between vowels in English in the past? In Shakespeare's works you can see "over" spelt "o'er" and "never" spelt "ne'er". Does this "V-dropping" still exist in some English dialects?

This poem has a strict meter.  Two syllables there would not fit it.
See iambic pentameter

This doesn't fully answer the question. You can't just drop arbitrary sounds from any word to fit the meter; there's some reason why this is (or was) allowed with "never."

The OP says "I can maybe see why this contraction was used in poetry for a marginally shorter meter, but why does it exist in the first place?" That is, they're clear on metrical reasons, and are asking about history of usage.

I upvoted since it's something resembling an answer, but doesn't resolve the problems in the comments above, not to mention that meter only applies to poetry, so doesn't answer the main part of the question - why it was coined and used in general use (i.e. outside of poetry). Or is this a usage that came from and is exclusive to poetry? Maybe including the poem was a mistake on my part as I only intended it as an example.

The OED’s earliest reference is from 1275 in a poem. Wikipedia has an article on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_contraction.

@XanneI don't have my OED handy. What poem is that? Can you provide the attestation? Seems very early.

@TimR — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layamon%27s_Brut. and ner æft a-ȝen teon. wið þan he moste king beon.
